# Pandas datetime tz-aware

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am using pandas and one of the columns is the year and time structure. Something like

```
2017-10-06T00:00:00+00:00
```

At least at the beginning, I do not think I have ever assigned a time zone to it. And the current 'dtype' is 'object'

However, if I am trying to set a timezone by using

```
data[datetime] = pd.to_datetime(data[datetime], errors='coerce', yearfirst=True).dt.tz_localize('UTC')
```

An error pops up saying "Already tz-aware, use tz_convert to convert."

My question is, it is originally 'object', how can it be tz-awared? If it is tz-aware, what time zone it is using? And if I use tz_convert, will it change the values in the column?

Because I have another dataframe that can use tz_localize('UTC') without any issue. And I want to compare these two dataframes, so I don't want the values of the first dataframe change to something else if I use tz_convert('UTC').

Answer (score 2):

If you datetime was intended to be in UTC then tada you're done! For text like "2017-10-06T00:00:00+00:00" The '+00:00' implies that this is in the UTC timezone already.

If you know that this is incorrect because as you said, "do not think I have ever assigned a time zone to it." you can remove this localization to make the timezone 'naive'

```
df.index
Out[2]: DatetimeIndex(['2017-10-06 00:00:00+00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)

df.index.tz_localize(None)
Out[3]: DatetimeIndex(['2017-10-06'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Now that it is not localized, you can set a new timezone, and now convert to where it belongs.

```
df.index.tz_localize('America/New_York')
Out[8]: DatetimeIndex(['2017-10-06 00:00:00-04:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, America/New_York]', freq=None)

df.index.tz_localize('America/New_York').tz_convert('UTC')
Out[9]: DatetimeIndex(['2017-10-06 04:00:00+00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)
```